# Using only one instance of Redis with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, redis, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework and Redis to serve an API.

For each requests made by a client (there is quite a lot of clients), I need to get data from Redis.

Since I don't want to create a new redis for each connection, I've been using a global instance.

The way I do that at the moment is creating on top of my Serializers.py a global Redis:

```
GLOBAL_REDIS = redis.StrictRedis(None)
```

The problem with this approach is that I am creating a redis for each client.

What would be a best way to do that? Ideally, the redis would start when the app starts, and shut down at the same moment.

Thanks

Comment: I don't quite get what you're using redis here for? Are you using it as persistent data store (or cache)? or broker for pub-sub model?

Comment: When you say "create new redis" you do realize that your `redis.StrictRedis()` just creates a client connection, not an instance of a Redis server? It should be completely OK for each request to open and close a redis connection. That said, if you are doing your GLOBAL_REDIS thing at the top of serializers.py you are not creating a connection per client. You are creating a connection per process. When your server starts an WSGI process your serializers.py gets loaded and creates GLOBAL_REDIS object. Then as cients connect the same object gets re-used.

Comment: RohitJain: I am using redis as a broker for pub-sub model.
@MadWombat: You are absolutely right. To be honest I am not doing redis.StrictRedis() but I am calling an interface that I created which also creates a server (this is needed and cannot be changed unfortunately).
I was thinking about a pool system.
Is it possible to have a resource across workers ?

Comment: I am confused. You want to create a server instance on demand, but you want to share it among the clients... why not create a single server instance and just have clients connect to it? It cannot be a permission issue, since you can obviously create a server. It cannot be a security issue, since you are willing to share the same instance between clients. Why not run a dedicated redis server and just have django connect to it?